# Invoking a member function with object as arguments

Tags: c++, object

I am currently taking an intermediate c++ class with my university, and we've just done classes/polymorphism and so I decided to work on a little project of my own. This is not homework, figured I'd get that out of the way.

So I'm using SFML to make a little "idle" game. This consists of an entity class, with a class for a weapon and a class for an armor. I have 2 entities, being the player and "other", or the enemy. Everything has been good so far, but I am running into trouble when I am trying to invoke a member function on the entity class with an argument as another entity. 
Here are the two functions

```
/*
Simulates the entity attacking another entity
*/
void Entity::attackEntity(Entity other) {
    other.decreaseHP(5);
    if (other.getCurrentHP() <= 0) {
        killEntity(other);
    }
}

/*
Simulates main entity defeating another
*/
void Entity::killEntity(Entity other) {
    if (other.getEntityType() == "Enemy") {
        other.setXP(rand() % (other.getRequiredXP() / 9) + 1);
        addXP(other.getXP());
        //addXP(rand() % (rand() % (getRequiredXP() / 10) + 1) + getEntityLevel()); // testing
        addGold(rand() % getEntityLevel() + getEntityLevel());

        // Increment the level of the entity to give them better armor/weapon
        other.incrementLevel();
        // Regenerate a weapon and armor for the enemy
        other.setWeapon(other.getWeapon().generateRandomWeapon(other.getEntityLevel()));
        other.setArmor(other.getArmor().generateRandomArmor(other.getEntityLevel()));
    }
    else if (other.getEntityType() == "Player") {
        other.setXP(other.getXP() / 10);
        other.setCurrentHP(other.getMaxHP());
        other.refreshEntityInfo();
    }
}
```

Currently, in the main program, I am calling it as

```
if (clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() >= 1.0f) {
    player.attackEntity(enemy);
    clock.restart();
}
```

What I *want* the code to do is every 1 second, the player will "attack" the other entity, being enemy. This will decrease the health points of the other entity by 5, and when the other entity's health points drop below 1, it will "kill" the entity, granting the player experience and resetting the other entity's armor and weapon, which will give it new stats. 
However, what *is* happening, is nothing. Health points do not decrease.
Obviously I am doing something wrong here as it is not working.

I tested just calling the decreaseHP() method alone in the time loop and that works:

```
if (clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() >= 1.0f) {
    //player.attackEntity(enemy);
    player.decreaseHP(5);
    clock.restart();
}
```

but the way I supplied before using the attackEntity() method does not.

Here is the decreaseHP() method.

```
/*
    Decreases the entity's current health by amount
*/
void Entity::decreaseHP(int amount) {
    setCurrentHP(getCurrentHP() - amount);
}
```

Do I need to pass the other entity object as reference? Am I going about these functions in a poor way? How should I be approaching this?

Edit -- So I know I just posted this, but I changed the parameters for both the attackEntity() function and killEntity() function so it takes the entity object by reference, and that seemed to solve the solution.

```
/*
Simulates main entity defeating another
*/
void Entity::killEntity(Entity &other) {
    if (other.getEntityType() == "Enemy") {
        other.setXP(rand() % (other.getRequiredXP() / 9) + 1);
        addXP(other.getXP());
        //addXP(rand() % (rand() % (getRequiredXP() / 10) + 1) + getEntityLevel()); // testing
        addGold(rand() % getEntityLevel() + getEntityLevel());

        // Increment the level of the entity to give them better armor/weapon
        other.incrementLevel();
        // Regenerate a weapon and armor for the enemy
        other.setWeapon(other.getWeapon().generateRandomWeapon(other.getEntityLevel()));
        other.setArmor(other.getArmor().generateRandomArmor(other.getEntityLevel()));
    }
    else if (other.getEntityType() == "Player") {
        other.setXP(other.getXP() / 10);
        other.setCurrentHP(other.getMaxHP());
        other.refreshEntityInfo();
    }
}

/*
Simulates the entity attacking another entity
*/
void Entity::attackEntity(Entity &other) {
    other.decreaseHP(5);
    if (other.getCurrentHP() <= 0) {
        killEntity(other);
    }
}
```

However, my last questions still stand: am I going about this the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature `void Entity::attackEntity(Entity other)` causes `other` to be a copy of the entity.  Any changes made to `other` are local to the `attackEntity` function.

If you need the changes to persist from the source item, the most straight forward way is to pass `other` in by reference, changing the signature to:  `void Entity::attackEntity(Entity& other)`

Comment: I actually just updated the OP cause I changed it to this and it works. But am I going about this the right way? Should I be using pointers?

Comment: @Carousser, no, Don't use pointers. This is what references are designed for.

Comment: @Carousser _"I actually just updated the OP cause I changed it to this and it works"_ Don't do that please!

Comment: Thank you Chad and Roddy for the insight. I updated the OP because I still wanted to know if what I was doing was not only legal, but "well perceived" as I do not want to get in the habit of poor conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Given this...

```
void Entity::attackEntity(Entity other) {
```

... then this code

```
Entity x;
foo.attackEntity(x);
```

... will create a COPY of X, pass that to attackEntity, which modifies the local copy that's immediately discarded. So x stays unchanged.

In this case, use pass by reference.

```
void Entity::attackEntity(Entity &other)
```

If the method isn't meant to modify x, use pass by const reference instead:

```
bool Entity::isWithinRange(const Entitiy &other)
```

Following from your edit, yes, references are absolutely the correct way of handling this. Passing objects by value (or as pointers) is often a code 'smell'.

Comment: thanks for the insight. I just wanted to make sure I was going about things in the right manner and not to get in any bad habits. Unfortunately, I can only mark 1 answer as correct... but again, thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

Check your use of the equality operator, "==". C++ doesn't treat strings the way Java and C# do. Quoted strings (e.g. "Enemy") decompose into pointers, so the comparison becomes "does this pointer point to the same address as the other pointer does," the answer to which will pretty much always be "no."

You can try using the std::string type, which defines a compare() method, but in general, C++ strings are only slightly friendlier than C strings.

You should probably be using the old-fashioned C string comparison functions such as strcmp().

Comment: Suggesting strcmp is seriously wrong. Assuming he's using ANY sensible C++ string type the equality comparisons are absolutely correct and idiomatic. I'd fire anyone trying to use strcmp.

Comment: I am currently using c++ strings, including <string> and using std::string, so I believe what I am doing here is perfectly legal. getEntityType() returns a c++ string type.

Comment: std::string doesn't define an operator==(), so you'll need to use std::string::compare() if you want to compare the contents of two strings.

Comment: @binky. Of course it does. It defines many, including between std:string and char*, which is  what's happening here. You do NOT need compare(). 
    .http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp